# what is the relationship between external accessory and protocol string

Tags: ios, swift, external-accessory

I have to say sorry before, my english's not good.

I'm working on a project related to "external accessory framework".
I need to fetch some data stream from our product through a "USB to lightning" adapter.
I've been spinning my wheel for several days.

My question here is "what's the exact way to use the framework".
I found something on apple dev forum:
[pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RjFKi.png)

Does it mean that if i have a "USB to lightning" adapter and its protocol string(For now, we're not going to make our own adapter, we plan to work with another company), then I plug our product to it, my app would be notified of the attachment or removal of the accessory.

Am i right?

I'm confusing right now, cause a colleague of mine contacted a adapter vendor, and they told her there is ***NO*** such thing called "protocol string".
I guess for some reason they just don't want us to know.

thanks!

Comment: If the USB adapter you are using is intended to provide generic USB connectivity to developers then presumably it is MFi certified and you will need to work with the information from that company as to how you integrate with their product and then with the USB device in the other side of it. If you are trying to use the Apple camera adapter then you will think of something else.

Comment: I tried to work with Apple camera adapter once, turned out it has no protocol string. So I think there is no way my app can communicate with Apple adapter. Now I'm looking for information about how to communicate with third-party adapter(MFi certified). And protocol string seems a key to me to do it.

Comment: The protocol string is used to match your app to the MFi certified adapter; you will need to get this from the adapter vendor and if you are going to add your app to the App Store then I believe that they need to submit paperwork authorising your app to use their hardware.  How you communicate with the USB device through the adapter will need to be provided by the adapter vendor

Comment: There is a protocol string - See https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ExternalAccessoryPT/Introduction/Introduction.html It is the identifier that identifies their MFi accessory.  If their business is providing adapters for use by application developers it is odd that they wouldn't provide all of the information that you need.

Comment: thanks @Paulw11! Maybe the project would be suspended for a while, this part(MFi) is real hassle to us. thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

```
You have set up these notifications for connection. Make you make connection through BT or USB. 
  /* Setup notification monitor */
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleAccessoryConnectNotification:) name:EAAccessoryDidConnectNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleAccessoryDisconnectNotification:) name:EAAccessoryDidDisconnectNotification object:nil];

    /* Turn on EA notifications */
    [[EAAccessoryManager sharedAccessoryManager] registerForLocalNotifications];
Once connection establishes you will get a call back with accessory info.

- (void) handleAccessoryConnectNotification:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    NSDictonary *earInfo = notification.userInfo;
   Print(@“Accessory Info: %@”,earInfo);
    // Get connected Accessory object.

    EAAccessory* currentAccessory = eaInfo[@"EAAccessoryKey"];
   // Create Session with base Protocol with Accessory.

    EASession*  currentEASession = [[EASession alloc] initWithAccessory:currentAccessory forProtocol:“com.accessory.base”];

    /* Open input and output steam */

    if ( self.currentEASession.inputStream && self.currentEASession.outputStream)
            {
                [[currentEASession inputStream] setDelegate:self];
                [[currentEASession inputStream] scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
                [[currentEASession inputStream] open];

                [[currentEASession outputStream] setDelegate:self];
                [[currentEASession outputStream] scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
                [[currentEASession outputStream] open];
       }
}

- (void)handleAccessoryDisconnectNotification:(NSNotification*)notification {
   Print(@“Accessory Info: %@”notification.userInfo);
}
# Read and Write data delegate method 
- ( void ) stream: ( NSStream * ) aStream handleEvent: ( NSStreamEvent ) eventCode {
    @try
    {
        switch ( eventCode )
        {
            case NSStreamEventOpenCompleted:{
                Print(@“[%s] NSStreamEventOpenCompleted",__PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
                break;
            }
            case NSStreamEventHasSpaceAvailable:
            {
                /* Write data */
                break;
            }
            case NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable:
            {
                //TODO
                 /* Read data */
                static uint8_t buffer[65536];
                NSInteger n = 65536;
                while (n == 65536)
                {
                    n = [self.currentEASession.inputStream read:buffer maxLength:65536];

                }
                break;
            }
            case NSStreamEventErrorOccurred:
            {
                //TODO
                Print(@"[%s] NSStreamEventErrorOccurred",__PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
                break;
            }
            case NSStreamEventEndEncountered:
            {
                //TODO
                Print(@"[%s] NSStreamEventEndEncountered",__PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
                break;
            }
            default:
            {
                break;
            }
        }

    }
    @catch (NSException *exception)
    {
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Relation between external accessory and protocol is.

When you connect iOS device with accessory. You have to create a session between accessory and iOS device to read and write data. Protocol string will identifier unique connection between accessory and iOS device for sharing and writing data.

Same time one accessory can be connected with multiple iOS devices. Each device will have a unique connection or session in between and it will identify through protocol.